# OpenCV C++ Color Detection and Print Mac

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, opencv, video-processing

I'm new to OpenCV and am working on a video analysis project.  Basically, I want to split my webcam into two sides (left and right), and have already figured out how to do this.  However, I also want to analyze each side for red and green colors, and print out the amount of pixels that are red/green.  I must have gone through every possible blog to figure this out, but alas it still doesn't work.  The following code runs, however instead of detecting red as the code might suggest it seems to pick up white (all light sources and white walls).  I have spent hours combing through the code but still cannot find the solution.  Please help!  Also note that this is being run on OSX 10.8, via Xcode.  Thanks!

```
#include <iostream>
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
#include "opencv2/core/core.hpp"

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main( int argc, char** argv )
{
    VideoCapture cap(0); //capture the video from webcam

    if ( !cap.isOpened() )  // if not success, exit program
    {
        cout << "Cannot open the web cam" << endl;
        return -1;
    }

    namedWindow("HSVLeftRed", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
    namedWindow("HSVLeftGreen", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);


    while (true) {

        Mat image;
        cap.read(image);
        Mat HSV;
        Mat threshold;

        //Left Cropping
        Mat leftimg = image(Rect(0, 0, 640, 720));       

        //Left Red Detection
        cvtColor(leftimg,HSV,CV_BGR2HSV);
        inRange(HSV,Scalar(0,0,150),Scalar(0,0,255),threshold);
        imshow("HSVLeftRed",threshold);

        //Left Green Detection
        cvtColor(leftimg,HSV,CV_BGR2HSV);
        inRange(HSV,Scalar(still need to find proper min values),Scalar(still need to find proper max values),threshold);
        imshow("HSVLeftGreen",threshold);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're cropping a 640x720 area, which might not fit exactly your contents. Tip: Check your actual capture resolution with `capture.get(CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH)` and `capture.get(CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT)`. You might want to consider `Mat threshold` --> `Mat thresholded`. This is just some ranting :)

What I suspect is the actual issue is the threshold you use for HSV. According to [`cvtolor`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/miscellaneous_transformations.html#cvtcolor), section on RGB to HSV conversion,

> On output 0 <= V <= 1.

so you should use a float representing your V threshold, i.e. `150 -> 150/255 ~= 0.58` etc.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help.  So the Scalar values are HSV (not RGB)?  I found this off of some sample code.  Also, what do you recommend for a lenient red/green range?  I changed some things and the external interference was significantly less but it still couldn't recognize my red paddle.

Comment: Yes, when you use `inRange()`, that uses the threshold in the HSV, which is what you reference as input. Since what you're trying to find are pure colours, the thresholding can happen in RGB colour space, by simply thresholding, e.g. for a large G component *and* at the same time a low R and B components. I'd recomment to normalise luminance/brightness before the thresholding, for more robuts results, or to work in a normalised `rgb` colorspace (`r = R / (R+G+B)` etc).